# Selecting GPU with ffmpeg hwaccel

Tags: amazon-ec2, ffmpeg

In my project I need to make many edits of the same video

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i [input video] -ss [start time] -to [end time] -vcodec h264_nvenc [output video]
```

This command gave me a significant performance increase from using software decoding. However, I only used one GPU for this.

I'm trying to scale up to a p2.8x with 8 GPUs. I want to be able to create 8 sets of edits and map each set to a GPU to be processed in parallel.

How can I specify a GPU for FFmpeg to use?

Comment: From the ffmpeg info page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ffmpeg/info): **"Questions about interactive use of the ffmpeg command line tool are off-topic."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-gpu` option. The first GPU is 0, second is 1, and so on.

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -gpu 5 -i [input video] -ss [start time] -to [end time] -vcodec h264_nvenc -gpu 5 [output video]
```

You can list options for each encoder or decoder such as with `ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_nvenc`.